# Ajax call not working on document ready event in firefox

Tags: javascript, ajax, jqgrid

on loading jsp page in firefox , i am calling an ajax function,and that ajax function call a servlet.This servlet returns data in response.But as shown in code when I alert that data I get null value.

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'Servlet?methodName=A',
    type : "POST",
    datatype : 'json',
    success : function(data) {
    alert(data);
    var obj = $.parseJSON(data);

    }
});
```

Comment: Do you think there is enough information here for us to resolve your problem ?

Comment: Please provide more information concerning the problem.

Comment: from servlet i am setting data in response,but when i get that data in success it shows null.

Comment: **success**: function(data){
  var obj = $.parseJSON(data);                               on alerting data,it shows null.

Comment: @NIKUNJSANGHADIA: You should modify the text of your question and include more full javaScript code. Instead of writing "Server is sending data" you could include an example of the JSON/XML or HTML data which returns the servlet. Additionally you used "jqgrid" tag, but the current text has *no relation to jqGrid*. If you have problem with loading grid content from the server you should include the code which should how you create jqGrid.

Answer (score 0):

check what you send from the function it should be it json return type so that you can get data